# Facebook's iPhone application -- User Interface for Inbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to figure out implement a Compose New Message view that works in the same way the Facebook iPhone application does theirs. It's very similar to `MFMailCompose` and `MFMessageCompose` but both of those are already set to search through the iPhone's contacts. Facebook's application looks exactly the same except theirs searches through your Facebook friends. I can use a `UISearchBar` to basically get the exact same functionality by displaying a `UITableView`, but I'd like to know how the Facebook app does it cause it looks a little bit nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Three20 UI](http://three20.info/overview#UI) is exactly what you find. It is the library used for Facebook App

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, this library is awesome hahah